# How to use dropbox datastore API without memory leaks?

Tags: dropbox-api

I have following simple code that tests Dropbox datastore API:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/dropbox-datastores-1.1-latest.js"/></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        client = new Dropbox.Client({key: 'mykey', token: 'mytoken'});
        var manager = client.getDatastoreManager();
        manager.openDefaultDatastore(function(err, store) {
          if (!err) {
            setInterval(function() {
              var table = store.getTable('foo');
              var record = table.get('bar');
              record.update({baz: 0});
              console.log(record.getSize());
            }, 1000);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

If i execute it, the reported record size will start increasing by 100 bytes on each update. Upon reaching 100kb code will fail with internal "record too big" error. Is it any way to update single Dropbox Datastore record in a loop without memory leaks? Maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Cross-linking to the same question on the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119469.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in the library, need to wait for a fix: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119469